# Subdivision surface modifier pulls mesh apart?

Tags: subdivision-surface

A mesh consists of two disconnected parts, which look connected to the eye. It is not ideal, but the geometry is generated through geometry nodes, which doesn't seem to offer an option to gracefully merge the parts? The problem here is that a subsurf modifier rounds the parts independently, which disconnects them to the eye. I guess this is the nature of the subsurf modifier. Is there any workaround, which keeps the parts together?
[image]

[image]

Comment: would you mind providing blend file?

Comment: Provided the .blend file.

Comment: Well, the two pipes are not connected, smoothing them works separately on both of them.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann this is the answer.

Comment: No. This is mentioned in the question, what I'm asking for is a workaround.

Comment: @eezacque You don't get what we want to say. Subdivision Surface will only treat it as one piece when it is one piece. So you have to edit the mesh to make it one piece. Is there a reason why this basic mesh has to be done in Geometry Nodes? Anyway, it is no longer a GN mesh (there's no GN modifier on the object), so you can edit it manually.

Comment: I think we're on the same page, I just wonder whether there is a workaround. This basic mesh is just a MWE, reduced to its bare essence, as I don't want to waste your time with a tree generated through several tens of geometry nodes. This tree is constructed as trunk and several layers of branches, joined through a Join Geometry node, which creates a loose join, meaning that the result cannot be effectively subsurfed, as it seems...